# Parse Html using lxml and xpath

Tags: python, xpath, html-parsing, lxml

I am trying to use lxml with python because after reading and doing google recommendation is to use lxml over other parsing packages. I have following dom structure and I manage write the correct xpath and I double check my xpath on xpath check to confirm the validity of it. Xpath works fine on Xpath Checker but when I put it with lxml in python I am not getting results infract I get object instead of actual text.

Here is my dom structure:

```
<div class="pdsc-l">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<td width="35%" valign="top">
<font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Brand</font>
</td>
<td width="65%" valign="top">
<font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">HTC</font>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="35%" valign="top">
<td width="65%" valign="top">
```

Following xpath that I wrote gives me what I want..

```
//td//font[text()='Brand']/following::td[1]
```

But with lxml I am nto getting the result:

```
This is my code:
    rawPage = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    read = rawPage.read()
    #print read
    tree = etree.HTML(read)    
    for tr in tree.xpath("//tr"):
        print tr.xpath("//td//font[text()='Brand']/following::td[1]")
```

Here is the out put

```
[<Element td at 0x10ad80b90>]
[<Element td at 0x10ad80b90>]
[<Element td at 0x10ad80b90>]
[<Element td at 0x10ad80b90>]
[<Element td at 0x10ad80b90>]
[<Element td at 0x10ad80b90>]
[<Element td at 0x10ad80b90>]
[<Element td at 0x10ad80b90>]
[<Element td at 0x10ad80b90>]
[<Element td at 0x10ad80b90>]
[<Element td at 0x10ad80b90>]
[<Element td at 0x10ad80b90>]
[<Element td at 0x10ad80b90>]
[<Element td at 0x10ad80b90>]
[<Element td at 0x10ad80b90>]
[<Element td at 0x10ad80b90>]
[<Element td at 0x10ad80b90>]
[<Element td at 0x10ad80b90>]
[<Element td at 0x10ad80b90>]
[<Element td at 0x10ad80b90>]
[<Element td at 0x10ad80b90>]
[<Element td at 0x10ad80b90>]
[<Element td at 0x10ad80b90>]
[<Element td at 0x10ad80b90>]
[<Element td at 0x10ad80b90>]
[<Element td at 0x10ad80b90>]
```

I tried it with following change but still i don't get the result, The code I wrote has the url, hopefully that will help for a better answer:

```
from lxml import etree
from lxml.html import fromstring, tostring
    url = 'http://www.ebay.com/ctg/111176858'
    request = urllib2.Request(url)
    rawPage = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    read = rawPage.read()
    #print read
    tree = etree.HTML(read)    
    for tr in tree.xpath("//tr"):
        t = tr.xpath("//td//font[text()='Brand']/following::td[1]")[0]
        print tostring(t)
```

Comment: maybe post the output you're getting so we can know a bit more what's going on?

Answer (score 9):

appending a `[0].text` to the end of the print statement in your answer should give you what you want. Basically, what's being printed in your question are single-element lists of `lxml.etree._Element`s, which have attributes like `tag` and `text` that you can use to get different properties. So, try

```
tr.xpath("//td//font[text()='Brand']/following::td[1]")[0].text
```

Comment: I am getting an index out of bound with your answer

Comment: hmm i still get all None values

Comment: i believe the text attribute of your `<td>` element is None because your `<td>` elements don't directly contain text. you might change your xpath to access the nested elements (eg `<font>`) which contain text as a direct child

Comment: I will try that but when I try this on xpath checker in firefox I get the text